# How to change the color of the TextField selection

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How to change the color of the textfield 'select' like this image:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZN9Xd.png)

In this image have the background selection blue and the options grey, but in flutter, how can I change this color?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `ThemeData`, you have the option for a `TextSelectionTheme` (recent versions have migrated to this, if you are using an older version the properties are individual properties on `ThemeData`. [Here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextSelectionTheme-class.html) are the docs for it and an example from the migration [docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/text-selection-theme):

```
ThemeData(
  textSelectionTheme: TextSelectionThemeData(
    cursorColor: Colors.red,
    selectionColor: Colors.green,
    selectionHandleColor: Colors.blue,
  )
)
```

EDIT: If you just want to change a single widget's theme, you can wrap your build function with the `Theme` widget like this:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme(
        child: MyWidget(),
        data: ThemeData(
            textSelectionTheme: TextSelectionThemeData(
          cursorColor: Colors.red,
          selectionColor: Colors.green,
          selectionHandleColor: Colors.blue,
        )));
  }
```

Comment: Where I put this? Currently I only have the textfield

Comment: Generally you have a `MaterialApp` main widget somewhere. You put it in there as the `theme`. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html

Comment: But I dont like all my code became with this color, I just wanna change only 2 fields, how it can be done?

Comment: @Mortyson this should do this, I would be writing the same answer but there wouldn't be a sense of writing duplicates I guess‍♂️