# Change TextField cursor bottom indicator in Flutter

Tags: flutter, cursor, textfield

I want to change cursor color, completely. I have added following code:

```
TextField(
  ...
  cursorColor: myBlueColor,
)
```

However, this does not change bottom indicator (when you select part of the text/text position) - it is still purple:

[image]

Can somebody help how to achieve this? I am using Flutter 3.16.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `MaterialApp`, you can change the `selectionHandleColor` for the `TextSelectionThemeData`:

```
theme: ThemeData(
  textSelectionTheme: TextSelectionThemeData(
    cursorColor: Colors.red,
    selectionColor: Colors.green,
    selectionHandleColor: Colors.black,
  ),
)
```

Comment: Is it possible to change that not in `ThemeData`? In the app, I have two different situations, two different selection handle colors. I need to change it per screen.

Comment: If anyone ever comes across this: It was not possible until recently due to a [bug](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/74890#ref-commit-1daac1b). Since it was fixed, you can use the theme widget as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64969643/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-textfield-selection)

Answer (score 1):

Change the `primarySwatch` color of `ThemeData` in `MaterialApp` of your root widget tree:

```
 MaterialApp(
   title: 'Flutter Demo',
   theme: ThemeData(
     primarySwatch: Colors.green,
   ),
    ...
 )
```

Comment: Currently, I have `primarySwatch: Colors.blue`, but the color on the image is Purple.

Comment: @Tom11 You can try to override the cupertinoOverrideTheme like: ```dart
cupertinoOverrideTheme: CupertinoThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.red) ```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to modify the `ThemeData` of your app which can be done either by wrapping your app with a Theme widget, or by setting the theme property of the `MaterialApp` widget. Here is a sample as how you can use the latter mentioned approach to achieve your requirement:

```dart
return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.red,
        textSelectionTheme: TextSelectionThemeData(
          cursorColor: Colors.red, // Change the cursor color. Change red to blue or as per your requirement
          selectionHandleColor: Colors.red, // Change the selection handle color
          selectionColor: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.5), // Change the text selection color
        ),
      ),
// ...Rest of code
```

***[DARTPAD DEMO](https://dartpad.dev/?id=3f3806756346d04db74d83ac725dbfe4)***