# How do I set the cursor, selection and selection handle color of a single TextField in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

The colors mentioned in the title use the theme set in the material app by default:

```
MaterialApp {
    theme: ThemeData(
        textSelectionTheme: TextSelectionThemeData(
            cursorColor: Colors.blue,
            selectionColor: Colors.blue,
            selectionHandleColor: Colors.blue,
        )
    ),
}
```

But how can I set those colors to a different value for a single TextField?

Comment: Please refer this stackoverflow question. May be this can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77563217/change-textfield-cursor-bottom-indicator-in-flutter

Comment: I htink that describes the global method, but not one for a single TextField. Though, I'm not sure given the lack of context there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Theme` class which takes in input a ThemeData and a child Widget.

You can check the official docs : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Theme-class.html  (timestamp of example in video at 2:15)

```
Theme(data : ThemeData(
    textSelectionTheme: TextSelectionThemeData(
        cursorColor: Colors.blue,
        selectionColor: Colors.blue,
        selectionHandleColor: Colors.blue,
    )
), child : TextField()
)
```